# set radio button true by textbox value?

Tags: php, javascript

I need the radio button to be checked when i change the value in the text box

```
radio button value 100.00rs                     input hidden array 10 clients     
radio button value 200.00 - 250.00rs            input hidden array 30 clients    
radio button value 250.00 - 300.00rs            input hidden array 50 clients    
radio button value 300.00 - 350.00rs            input hidden array 75 clients    
radio button value 350.00 - 400.00rs            input hidden array 100 clients
```

these values are fetching by mysql-php foreach loop 
when i change the values of textbox by using javascript onchange function the radio button should be selected based on the value.
for example 
if i input 10 in the text box 1st radio button  should be selected
else if i input values between 200-250 second  radio button  should be selected

```
function onChangeTest() {
var radio = document.getElementsByName("amt[1]") 
var qty2 = document.getElementsByName("max[]") 
var input = document.getElementById('ts').value;
    for(var i=0;i<radio.length;i++){
        if(input < qty2[i].value ){  // if input is < or between radio button value
        //document.getElementByName('amt[2]').checked = true;
        alert(radio[i].value + '\n' + qty2[i].value + '\n' +  input + '\n' + i) ; 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: [live-example](http://jsfiddle.net/) please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you're asking how to check a radio button via a text field.

Basically:

```
pseudocode
if text value == "true", then
    set radio button to true
```

This can be done in the following way

```
HTML
<input type="text" id="txt">
<input type="radio" id="rad">

JAVASCRIPT
txt.onkeyup = function(){
    if(txt.value == 'true'){
        rad.checked = true;
    }else{
        rad.checked = false;
    }
}
```

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/B1KMusic/G32NC/)